# How to save (not as a blender file)

Tags: saving

I know where the "save" button is, I save but it`s a blender file in my files. I need it to be a 3d object that I can view in my laptops 3d viewer. It was that way when I first saved it, now it saves it automatically as a blender file. Can some one help?

Answer (score 3):

You want to export your model, rather than save the file.[image: export menu]

You need to know which file format your 3d viewer uses and select it from the menu.  Not all of the export formats are enabled by default.  You need to go to user preferences (CTRL-ALT-U), switch to the addons tab and look for the right exporter[image: user preferences]

You can find most of the exporters by selecting the import-export category.

If the exporter you want isn't there, then search for the question 'how do I export files of type